# choosing oldest valued cell when 2 columns have same value but third column has differing values (SQL)

Tags: distinct

In SQL, I have three columns, the first two are values to create distinction for a person. The third column will have different values for each person (dates). How do I select the row for each person with the oldest valued date?

[image]

should output:
John Plumber 1/3/2020
Elizabeth Teacher 12/1/2020

Comment: Read about `group by` and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT First Name, 
       Job, 
       MIN(Day of material)  
FROM table  
GROUP BY First Name, Job
```

EASY!!!